# problems with adding product Quanitity via a detail page

Tags: php, logic, laravel-8, laravel-blade, shopping-cart

i'm new to laravel and i want to add quantity via detail page
the probleme is it return this error.
`Attempt to read property "quatity" on null`
when i comment the part responsable for that and i click increase the quantity get increased in the cart directly without clicking to the submit button.
what i want is to increase and decrease without sending it directly to the db i want to increase and then click submit to send it when i use the form with post method and @csrf it return this error `The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD`

```
<div style="margin-bottom:20px">    
      <div class="quantity">
      <a href="{{route('decrQtePanier',['id'=> $prod->id])}}" class="quantity-button minus">
        <i class="klbth-icon-minus"></i>
      </a>
     <input value="{{$prod->pivot->quatity}}" name="cart[15945][qty]" type="text" id="quantity_61a9f089c4906" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="1" max="11" size="4" placeholder="" inputmode="numeric" />
    <a href="{{route('incrQtePanier',['id'=> $prod->id])}}" class="quantity-button plus">
    <i class="klbth-icon-plus"></i>                                                        
    </a>
   </div>
   <a style="text-decoration:none; " href="{{ url('add-to-cart/'.$prod->id) }}">
  <button style="border-radius: 50px; padding:0 20px; margin-left:40px" type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="352" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">
          Ajouter
  </button>
</a>
```

this is my increase and decrease methods the methods works fine in the shoppingcart

```
public function decrease($id)

    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $panier = $user->panier;
        foreach ($panier->produits as $produit) {

            if ($produit->id == $id) {
                $qt = $produit->pivot->quantite;
                $qt--;
                if ($qt == 0) {
                    $panier->produits()->detach($produit->id);
                } else $panier->produits()->updateExistingPivot($produit->id, ['quantite' => $qt]);
            }
        }
        return redirect()->back();
    }




    public function increase($id)

    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $panier = $user->panier;

        foreach ($panier->produits as $produit) {

            if ($produit->id == $id) {
                $qt = $produit->pivot->quantite;
                $qt++;
                $panier->produits()->updateExistingPivot($produit->id, ['quantite' => $qt]);
            }
        }

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

those are my routes

```
Route::get('/deletePanier/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\PanierController@destroy')->middleware('auth')->name("deletePanier");
Route::get('/decreasePanier/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\PanierController@decrease')->middleware('auth')->name("decrQtePanier");
Route::get('/add-to-cart/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\PanierController@addToCart')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/detail/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\HomePageController@product_detail');
```

Comment: Show your routes file - probably web.php - as the initial indication is that the route. you want to submit your form to is not defined as a POST route.

Comment: `Route::get('/detail/{id}','App\Http\Controllers\HomePageController@product_detail');`this is my route it's already there in the question i know its a get route because i want to get the product details and then add that product in the cart table

Comment: OK - is there a reason you are trying to involve the controller when you increase or decrease the quantity? Can you not just have buttons which, through javascript, increase or decrease the value of the quantity input field when clicked, and then worry about what the quantity is when the form is submitted?

Comment: yes i need it to fill the column quatity in the databas, and i don't know how to do it with javascript i never worked with it before, the controllers works just fine in the shoppingcart the same code

Comment: Please show the <form> tag, including the destination to which the form is submitted.

Comment: yes posted the form as an answer

Answer (score 0):

@Giles Bennett when i remove the form tag the add to cart link works just fine the main problem in this case is whith the input quantity

```
<form method="post" style="margin-bottom:20px">    
     @csrf
       <!-- quantity numbers inputs -->
       <div class="quantity">
      <a href="{{route('decrQtePanier',['id'=> $prod->id])}}" class="quantity-button minus">
       <i class="klbth-icon-minus"></i>
        </a>
       <input value="{{$prod->pivot->quatity}}" name="cart[15945][qty]" type="text" id="quantity_61a9f089c4906" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="1" max="11" size="4" placeholder="" inputmode="numeric" />
                                                        <a href="{{route('incrQtePanier',['id'=> $prod->id])}}" class="quantity-button plus">
                                                            <i class="klbth-icon-plus"></i>
                                                            
                                                        </a>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <!-- quantity numbers inputs -->
                                                    <a style="text-decoration:none; " href="{{ url('add-to-cart/'.$prod->id) }}">
     <button style="border-radius: 50px; padding:0 20px; margin-left:40px" type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="352" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">
         Ajouter
      </button>
   </a>

  </form>
```